# angularjs amount of method calls in in-include with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

We need to render a tree structure with angularjs. We are doing it with recursive templates, and it works before we have more than 100 items in the tree. What I noticed it that `getTemplate` method is called multiple times.

I know that its ok for angular to do that, but as for me it is too much. In this simple [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tDAL5I0L5qVR4JYxhjaa?p=preview) `getTemplate` method is called 9 times, I don't believe that this won't hurt the performance.

In our real case with recursive template amount of get template is just insane and can reach 100 for 3 items in tree.

Is there any way to optimize ng-include somehow? Sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/tDAL5I0L5qVR4JYxhjaa?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the code gets reevaluated everytime there is a new digest cycle, to check if anything has changed :

```
<ng-include src="itemTemplate(i)"></ng-include>
```

That's why you got so much calls.

I think the best solution is to put all your tree data in a data structure like an array, put in on the scope, and only then, render it.

Example here
[on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/snKqDM9DeEz6SBaaEsZ5?p=preview)